# converting series to dataframe using 'as_index' not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to convert this series of data into dataframe using as_index = False inside groupby method. My goal is to show the total value for month and weekday.

**My data**

```
        Dispatching      Pickup_date     Affiliated locationID month weekDay day hour minute
    0   B02617     2015-05-17 09:47:00   B02617       141      5  Sunday 17   9 47
    1   B02617     2015-05-17 09:47:00   B02617       65       5 Sunday  17   9 47
```

This is my main data uber-15. From this I am extracting month and weekDay.
[extracting month and weekDay data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgqd6.jpg)

```
temp = uber_15.groupby(['month', "weekDay"]).size()
```

Next I am converting this series to dataframe using as_index.

```
temp = uber_15.groupby(['month', "weekDay"], as_index=False).size()
```

But the result is same when I use as_index=False but not working.
[as_index result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWHJm.jpg)

I also tried finding online solution where I find about reset_index but this there is column header with "0" which was supposed to be 'size' with reset_index.
[using reset_index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS4rn.jpg)

```
temp = uber_15.groupby(['month', "weekDay"]).size().reset_index()
```

This the goal I am trying to achieve. [goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NQcv.png)
this is the output I am getting. [my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4rT5.png)